# Registering services in external assembly in IdentityServer3

Tags: autofac, identityserver3

I need to add registrations to interfaces whose implementations are internal to assemblies referenced by my `IdentityServer3` factory.

The only mechanism I can think of to do this is to expose another DI container (also using `Autofac`) which uses module registrations, one of which is present and defines the registrations within this referenced assembly. Then, I can do the following:

```
factory.Register(new Registration<IUsersService>(resolver =>
{
    using (ILifetimeScope scope = Global.GlobalContainerProvider.ApplicationContainer.BeginLifetimeScope())
    {
        return scope.Resolve<IUsersService>();
    }
}
```

Is there an elegant way that actually uses the internal `Autofac` container within `IdentityServer3`?

Comment: You may be stuck. [I had similar issues and filed an enhancement request.](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3/issues/2117)

Comment: Thank you. I pretty much thought this was the case.